# Send query as parameter to SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a SQL tabled-value function that will receive a query as n parameter through my API. In my function I want execute that query. The query will be a SELECT statement.

This is what I have done so far and what to achieve but it is not the correct way to do so.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CUSTOM_EXPORT_RESULTS ( 
    @query varchar(max),
    @guid uniqueidentifier,
    @tableName varchar(200))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Execute query into a table
    SELECT * 
    INTO @tableName
    FROM (
        EXEC(@query)
    ) 
)
GO
```

Please suggest the correct way!

Comment: SQL Server? Or a different database system? Please add a suitable tag. For SQL Server, you cannot execute ad-hoc SQL from within a function.

Comment: Why you use function for export? More preferable use stored procedure for this.

Comment: what do you mean by "Execute query into a table"

Comment: In my API I will call the function which will return the results for the query that has been send through. My function will return the data inside my @tableName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_CUSTOM_EXPORT_RESULTS

       @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.test'
     , @guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
     , @tableName VARCHAR(200) = 'test2'

AS BEGIN

     SELECT @query = 
          REPLACE(@query, 
               'FROM', 
               'INTO [' + @tableName + '] FROM')

     DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
     SELECT @SQL = '
     IF OBJECT_ID (N''' + @tableName + ''') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE [' + @tableName + ']
     ' + @query

     PRINT @SQL
     EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

     RETURN 0

END
GO
```

Output -

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'test2') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE [test2]
SELECT * INTO [test2] FROM dbo.test
```

Answer (score 3):

What I see in your question is encapsulation of:

- taking a dynamic SQL expression
- executing it to fill a parametrized table

Why do you want to have such an encapsulation?

First, this can have a negative impact on your database performance. Please read [this on EXEC() and sp_executesql()](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Introducing) . I hope your SP won't be called from multiple parts of your application, because this WILL get you into trouble, at least performance-wise.

Another thing is - how and where are you constructing your SQL? Obviously you do it somewhere else and it seems its manually created. If we're talking about a contemporary application, there are lot of OR/M solutions for this and manual construction of TSQL in runtime should be always avoided if possible. Not to mention EXEC is not guarding you against any form of SQL injection attacks. However, if all of this is a part of some database administration TSQL bundle, forget his paragraph.

At the end, if you want to simply load a new table from some existing table (or part of it) as a part of some administration task in TSQL, consider issuing a SELECT ... INTO ... This will create a new target table structure for you (omitting indexes and constraints) and copy the data. SELECT INTO will outperform INSERT INTO SELECT because [SELECT INTO gets minimally logged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

I hope this will get you (and others) at least a bit on the right track.

Answer (score -5):

You can use stored procedure as well, here is the code that you can try.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CUSTOM_EXPORT_RESULTS 
(   
    @query varchar(max),
    @guid uniqueidentifier,
    @tableName varchar(200)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    declare @strQuery nvarchar(max)
    -- Execute query into a table
    SET @strQuery = REPLACE(@query,'FROM', 'INTO '+@tableName+' FROM')
    exec sp_executesql @strQuery
)
GO
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. You can't execute ad-hoc SQL from within a function.